# Ajax get call ,getting error ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to refresh content of my page every after few mili seconds.my code works fine for few seocnds but after sometime it went to error block and console display :: ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES 
Attaching code herewith :

```
$(function(){
    var refresh_count = 100;
    {% if 'msg' in entry.keys() %}
        var contentVal = "abc"
        console.log(contentVal);
        $('#content').append(contentVal);
    {% end %}  

    function refreshDiv() {
        var queryStr = "";
        $("#{{ entry["tid"] }} input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
            var name = "&";
            name = name + $(this).attr('name');
            queryStr = queryStr + name + "=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,     
            type: 'get',
            url: 'getddata', 
            data: 'data=' + queryStr,
            success: function(result) {
                if (refresh_count > 0) {  
                    $('#content').html('');
                    //result = result.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;', '>').replace('&quot;', '"');
                    result = result.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;', '>');
                    //alert(result);
                    $('#content').append(result);
                }   
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                $('#content').html('<span class="label label-danger"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Error While Loading</span>');
            }
        });
    }

    if (refresh_count > 0) {   
        setInterval(refreshDiv, 4000);  
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have replcaed setInterval with setTimeout and its working fine.